# Is there a way to define a Joi schema from a variable?

Tags: javascript, json, joi

I'm trying to send a Joi validation schema via a variable i.e.

```
params: {
  centre: Joi.object().keys({
    lat: Joi.number().min(-90).max(90).required(),
    lon: Joi.number().min(-180).max(180).required()
  }),
  raduis: Joi.number().min(1).max(100),
  threshold: Joi.number().required()
}
```

I'm hoping at the other side to perform the following

```
schema = Joi.object().keys(params);
```

Problem is that I'm returning the params amonst other things

```
return { params, var1 };
```

I'm getting "errorMessage": "Converting circular structure to JSON" back from Lambda function.

If I dont return the params variable then the function succeeds.

Background on why I want to do this.

Think of it as I'm the backend and I want to express a schema to a client for the purposes of not only validating user input but also assisting in building a dynamic UX based on the schema returned.

Any ideas?

Comment: As I understand it, you need a key called ‘params’ in your scheme?

Comment: @SerShubham No not really. params is the object I was returning that contained the schema

Since digging around I've come to the conclusion with others here that sending Joi schema is never likely to work as its way too circular under the hood.

For backend to client schema stuff we will look at 

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv

Should allow me to express the schema in pure json to client nicely we think